# if statement with string compare in C

Tags: c, if-statement, random, string-comparison, fgets

I'm supposed to write a short C code where I generate a random number between 1 and 6 if I type "random". If I type in "exit" or "quit", the program must end. "quit" and "exit" work, but nothing happens when I enter "random".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("enter your command");
    char input[100];
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    if (strcmp(input, "quit") == 0){
       exit(0); 
    } else if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
       exit(0);
    } else if (strcmp(input, "random") == 0) {
       srand(time(NULL));
       int random_number = rand() %7;
       printf("%d\n",random_number);     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One simple step would be to add an `else { printf("Huh? Got [%s]\n", input); }` at the end, which would show you what was happening.  Also, neither your `exit` nor `quit` comparisons is working; the program exits silently when they fail.  You could see that by adding `printf("Got quit [%s]\n", input);` before the `exit(0)` for `quit`, and similarly for `exit`.  You could also see this if you ran the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the new line character `'\n'` that can be appended to the string read by `fgets`.

For example

```
char input[100];
input[0] = '\0';

if ( fgets (input, 100, stdin) )
{
    input[strcspn( input, "\n" )] = '\0';
}
```

Take into account that the initializer in this declaration

```
int random_number = rand() %7;
```

generates numbers in the range `[0, 6]`. If you need the range `[1, 6]` then the initializer should look like

```
int random_number = rand() %6 + 1;
```

And according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `fgets` call is reading the inserted command plus the newline at the end. So you should compare with the newline as well, or choose a different input reading method (such as using `scanf`, useful for dealing with any whitespace, or removing the newline yourself).

```
strcmp(input, "quit\n") == 0
strcmp(input, "exit\n") == 0
strcmp(input, "random\n") == 0
```

You didn't notice with the first two commands, but they never passed the test as well.

You could also add a final `else` to grab anything not matched. Only altering that (without dealing with newlines) would prove that the others are not matching as well:

```
/* ... */
} else {
    printf("unknown command\n");
}
```

An example using `scanf`:

```
char input[101];
scanf(" %100s", input); /* discards any leading whitespace and
                         * places the next non-whitespace sequence
                         * in `input` */
```

Comment: Thank you my friend :) And kudos for noticing my mistake with random numbers I'm indeed supposed to get random numbers between 1 - 6.